# How to make an auto clicker with global start and stop key

Tags: bash, read

So I have an auto clicker script that is this simple command: [Tribute](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179581/how-can-i-make-my-mouse-auto-click-every-5-seconds#comment1144101_329009)

```
xdotool click --delay 5 --repeat 900000 1
```

I have to switch to the terminal and `Ctrl-C` interrupt the script to stop it. Then just run it again to restart.

So I started to use the `read` command to check for key input to avoid this switching back and forth. However that only checks for input at the terminal. I am clicking somewhere else, and want to be able to start and stop from there.

Is there a version of `read` that can check for keystrokes globally?

Comment: I'm not sure about something that's coded directly in the script itself, but another option is to use another keystroke to trigger a separate script that `kill`s the first script. I'm using KDE Plasma, which allows you to easily assign a script to arbitrary keystrokes from the GUI system settings.

Comment: That seems a bit hackish. I could see going that route, but hopefully there is a better way.

Comment: I feel like most things involving `xdotool` are hackish to begin with.

Comment: @Sparhawk Good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By typing `xinput --list`, you get a list of all the input devices in your system. You can also programmatically get the state of each key using `xinput --query-state DEVICE_ID`.

```
1 class :
KeyClass
    key[0]=up
    key[1]=up
    key[2]=up
...
```

First, you will need to figure out the keycode you want to use. You can do this by running `xinput --test DEVICE_ID`, and pressing the key.

```
key press   ###
key release ###
```

Once you find the correct key, make a script like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do

# Replace DEVICE_ID and KEYCODE.
inp=`xinput --query-state DEVICE_ID | grep -o 'button\[KEYCODE\]=down'`

if [ ! -z "$inp" ]; then

xdotool click 1

fi

done
```

This will spam click the mouse button while the user holds down a button

Answer (score 0):

You can use another extension - numlockx

Here's the idea.

you'd install xdotools and numlockx via `sudo apt-get install -y numlockx xdotool`

then you'd go ahead and use something like this.

```
DELAY=5
while true
do
  NUMLOCK=$(numlockx status)
    if [ "$NUMLOCK" == "Numlock is on" ]
    then
    xdotool click 1
    fi
  sleep $DELAY
done
```

This results in a global clicker with a 5 second delay associated to your numlock. you can change the delay to have it click at shorter intervals.